# Avoid hard coding storyboard IDs in 2 places

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

When I want to set an ID for a View Controller I go into the storyboard file, select the ViewController, then on the Identity inspector I type in the `Storyboard ID` as something like "theVCID":

[image]

When I want to use that View Controller in code I do something like:

```
UIViewController *myVC = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theVCID"];
```

Is there a way I can just hardcode this ID string in one location instead of hard coding it inside storyboard and when I use it in code?

If I could get a variable in the storyboard XML, I could just get the hardcoded string variable inside the XML source, but I don't know how/where to set up a variable so that the storyboard XML can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are forced to duplicate the declaration.

I wouldn't recommend parsing the XML as you will be basing that on the assumption of an implementation detail. Technically, storyboards could change their data type to anything in the future and this would break your implementation.

The safest way to do this is to keep your storyboard identifiers in a single class (say StoryBoardCoordinationController) and simply reference the storyboard objects through this single interface. Hopefully you should never be in the situation where these values are changing often, and if they are you should definitely seek to do something about it:)

Comment: I wasn't really talking about parsing the XML, but you made a good point as to why that would be bad. I was asking if there was a way to access a variable inside the XML source code. Like: `<viewController storyboardIdentifier=$variableName ...` But even if a solution like that existed it would be very susceptible to other developers not realizing what was going on, and changing the String in an undesirable location.